# Making the barcode bigger in size Itextsharp VB.net

Tags: vb.net, itext, barcode

This is the code that i'am using to make the barcode, but i am not able to make it bigger in size, any ideas ?

```
    Private Sub BarcodeGen()

    Dim Code39 As Barcode39 = New Barcode39()
    Code39.Code = TextBox.Text
    Code39.Size = 80.0F
    Code39.StartStopText = False
    Code39.GenerateChecksum = False
    Code39.Extended = False
    Dim Mem As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Code39.CreateDrawingImage(System.Drawing.Color.Black, System.Drawing.Color.White).Save("D:\BC.png")

End Sub
```

This is the generated barcode

[image]

Comment: Is there a `.BarHeight` property to make it taller, if that is what you want to do?

Comment: No, this make is taller not larger :(  the current size wont allow me to scan it with my phone ..

Comment: If the `.Size` parameter isn't helping, perhaps you could take the image and make that bigger.

Comment: Take care when resizing a barcode thats been generated, for example, if you scale the image by 1.5x you will begin losing and adding pixels that alter the spacing. This will return to bite you as the barcode will no longer be readable!

Comment: There are a lot of gray-tones in the image, scanners don't like that.  Most relevant detail is how you display that bitmap.  The code that [generates it](https://github.com/itextsharper/iTextSharp-4.1.6/blob/master/iTextSharp/text/pdf/Barcode39.cs#L342) is extremely simplistic, the image won't scale worth a lick.  Wrong approach as well, they should have generated a Metafile.  If you use, say, Graphics.DrawImage() then you need to use InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor.  Best to keep shopping.

Comment: If i resize it in paint, i'm able to read it with my phone.. i think i found a solution..

Comment: @HansPassant you have linked to the wrong repository. The correct link is https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/Barcode39.cs#L338